# Value doesn't show up when retrieved using requests.get

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm using Python to scrape a retailer website for its html. I looking for the data and attribute on their air conditioning products, such as Energy Efficiency, Constant or Variable Type, etc. etc. Hence, I used requests.get() and afterwards I plan to filter the data using regex or bs4.

```
file_number = 0
for portal in portals:
   item = requests.get(portal)
   item_text = str(item.text)
   file_number += 1
   file_name = "blah" + file_number.zfill(4) + ".txt"
   file = open(file_name,"w",encoding="utf8") 
   file.write(item_text)
   file.close()
```

I could retrieve all html pages from the set() I've compiled. However, the product price is missing. This piece of information is present if I go the page and directly right-click --> inspect.

The example below is just one instance of the differences. The two files are the same, except all references to the prices are omitted (Just a wild guess: the price could appear slightly differently depending on who's shopping, that's why there're stored separately somehow.)

Also be glad to listen to any suggestion on code improvement, I'm brand new to python!

requests.get() version of info

```
<div class="p-price">
<strong class="J-p-32965125681"></strong> <span>X <span class="J-buy-num"></span></span>
</div>
```

vs
right-click --> inspect version of info

```
<div class="p-price">
<strong class="J-p-32965125681">￥3499.00</strong> <span>X <span class="J-buy-num"></span></span>
</div>
```

Thank you so much!

By the way, disclaimer the robots.txt says:
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /?* 
And I'm not crawling any page that have "?" in their url so...

Answer (score 0):

Web Scraping is tricky!

At a first glance, the values seens to be added via javascript. In that case, you'll need to use a headless browser or extension to **scrap the DOM** after the page concludes loading, not the skeleton html page on the site.

Comment: Thanks alx! What does DOM stand for?